# resize canvas in p5 without clearing the content but rather mapping it to new size

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, processing, p5.js

visit this link to run the code in p5 web editor [here](https://editor.p5js.org/gadhahitesh@gmail.com/sketches/HiGYKtxiq)

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(280, 280);
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  strokeWeight(25);
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    stroke(255);
    line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
  }
}


function predict() {
  resizeCanvas(28, 28);
}
```

Trying to implement a digit classifier where a user will draw the digit and a neural network will classify, but the neural network is expecting a 28x28 image as it's trained of images of that dimension MNIST dataset but the thing is if the canvas is to small user will not be able to draw anything so what i want is to resize the canvas to 28x28 dimension and then loadpixels of canvas and do the remaining process. but when i do that the canvas is cleared so any suggestion on how to not lose the drawing but rather map it to new dimension.

---

Or may be this is not a good way to doing it in first place to resize a canvas and loading pixels
so any other idea of doing this is also welcome.. Thanku any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the p5 [scale()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/scale) function would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the content of the main canvas in another graphics object that has already the desired dimensions and then manipulate its pixels array:

```js
let cnv
function setup() {
  cnv = createCanvas(280, 280);
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  strokeWeight(25);
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    stroke(255);
    line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
  }
}

function predict() {
  //Auxiliar graphics object
  let resized = createGraphics(28, 28)

  //Draw and scale the canvas content
  resized.image(cnv, 0, 0, 28, 28)
  
  //Manipulate the new pixels array
  resized.loadPixels()
  console.log(resized.pixels)

  // Draw the 28x28 just for visual feedback
  image(resized, 0, 0) 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>

<button onClick="predict()">PREDICT</button>
```